# how to find the special characters in a string and split into words in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have string like this 'SUZUKI GSX_1300/TWOWHEELER'

Now I want to split the above string into words and inserting the one by one word into one table.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (a nvarchar(500));
declare @RTADESC nvarchar(100) = 'SUZUKI GSX_1300/TWOWHEELER';
declare @b int =1;
declare @c int;
set @c=CHARINDEX('_',@RTADESC,@b);

WHILE @c>0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @b= CHARINDEX('_' ,@RTADESC,@b)+1
            INSERT INTO @a
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@RTADESC,0,@b-1)
            set @c=CHARINDEX('_',@RTADESC,@b)
        END

        SELECT * FROM @a
```

Now I want to see the data in the table @a as below

```
SUZUKI
GSX
1300
TWOWHEELER
```

Based on it I will search for vehicle makers in my table.

So please help on this how I can split my string I may get different special characters as well in future.

Comment: An idea about split in SQL Server: http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/best-split-function-tsql-delimited.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create table function func_SplitString

   ```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_SplitString](@DelimitedString varchar(8000), @Delimiter varchar(100))
    RETURNS @tblArray TABLE ( ID int IDENTITY(1,1),Element varchar(1000))
    AS
    BEGIN
    -- Local Variable Declarations
    DECLARE @Index      smallint,
            @Start      smallint,
            @DelSize    smallint
    SET @DelSize = LEN(@Delimiter)
    -- Loop through source string and add elements to destination table array
    WHILE LEN(@DelimitedString) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @DelimitedString)
        IF @Index = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @tblArray (Element) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(@DelimitedString)))
                BREAK
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO   @tblArray (Element) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1))))
                SET @Start = @Index + @DelSize
                SET @DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, @Start , LEN(@DelimitedString) - @Start + 1)
            END
    END
    RETURN
   ```

   END
2. Use the function to split string like this 'SUZUKI GSX_1300/TWOWHEELER'

- Replace all special character to '_'
- Using func_SplitString

> ```
> SELECT * FROM func_SplitString (REPLACE(REPLACE('SUZUKI GSX_1300/TWOWHEELER',' ','_'),'/','_'), '_')
> ```